# Generic units in F#

Tags: generics, f#, units-of-measurement

When writing generic functions in F#, I can use members defined in LanguagePrimitives module, like e.g. in this function, that simply increments a number

```
let inline increment (x : 'a) =
    x + LanguagePrimitives.GenericOne
```

I wonder if there's anything similar to work with units of measure. In particular: is it possible to write a function that takes a generic argument and converts it to a number of the same type with a unit. Something like:

```
let inline toNumberWithUnit<[<Measure>] 'u> x =
    x * GenericOne<'u> //that won't work
```

This would have a type: 'a -> 'a<'u>. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That signature would be illegal in .NET so the only way will be to use F# inline feature with static constraints.

Then you can define a function like this:

```
[<Measure>]
type M = class end

let x = LanguagePrimitives.FloatWithMeasure<M> 2. 

type T<[<Measure>]'M>() =
    static member ($) (T, x) = LanguagePrimitives.FloatWithMeasure<'M> x
    static member ($) (T, x) = LanguagePrimitives.Float32WithMeasure<'M> x
    static member ($) (T, x) = LanguagePrimitives.Int32WithMeasure<'M> x
    // more overloads

let inline NumberWithMeasure x = T() $ x

let a: float<M>   = NumberWithMeasure 2.
let b: float32<M> = NumberWithMeasure 2.0f
let c: int<M>     = NumberWithMeasure 2
```

The main problem when dealing with generic numbers and units of measure is that you end up with those signatures where you a have a generic type with a type parameter (a [higher kind](http://adriaanm.github.io/files/higher.pdf) ) which at the moment are not supported in .NET.

**UPDATE**

After a while I ran into this situation as well and found this answer that happens to come from me :)

After trying it with different units of measures I realized it doesn't work, because the type inference doesn't generalize over units of measure, the posted example works because type inference witness the use with the `M` measure and then specializes the function over `M`.

However here's a way to make it work, by explicitly using the `$` operator above defined:

```
[<Measure>] type km
[<Measure>] type miles

type WithMeasure<[<Measure>]'M>() =
    static member ($) (x, T) = LanguagePrimitives.FloatWithMeasure<'M> x
    static member ($) (x, T) = LanguagePrimitives.Float32WithMeasure<'M> x
    static member ($) (x, T) = LanguagePrimitives.Int32WithMeasure<'M> x
    static member ($) (x, T) = LanguagePrimitives.DecimalWithMeasure<'M> x
    static member ($) (x, T) = LanguagePrimitives.Int16WithMeasure<'M> x
    static member ($) (x, T) = LanguagePrimitives.Int64WithMeasure<'M> x
    static member ($) (x, T) = LanguagePrimitives.SByteWithMeasure<'M> x
    // no more overloads


let a: float<km>      = 2.   $WithMeasure()
let b: float32<miles> = 2.0f $WithMeasure()
```

There might be a way to create a generic function, or a generic constant, but at the moment it seems not to be possible with the current version of F#.

I will try with F# 4.1 when it's ready.

Comment: So I can't have a generic function, but rather a sequence of functions and need to make it clear which one I'd like to use. Well - still not what I'd love to have, but as you say it's the best I can currently get it must be enough.
Thanks a lot, Sir :).